# VBA evaluates > and < operators incorrectly

Tags: vba, operator-keyword

I have the following simple code, which vba evaluates incorrectly (imho) and i can not figure it out even after searching the web extensively:

```
ElseIf TextBoxSNo.Value < 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Please choose existing S.No")
    Exit Sub
ElseIf TextBoxSNo.Value > Cells(LastRow, 1).Value Then
    MsgBox ("Please choose existing S.No")
    Exit Sub
```

This Code ristricts the values one can enter into an Excel userform. It works fine when the user enters a Value lower than 1 or higher than Cells(LastRow, 1).Value.

However, it also Shows me the error message when I enter a valid value. How can this be? I even checked the values the code evaluates by printing them out in the MsgBox along with the Error Message. It really seems like vba evaluates 5>100 as true and prints out the error message.

Edit: If I only Keep the first ElseIf Statement, it works as expected. Only when I add the second ElseIf, it evaluates incorrectly. LastRow is defined as an Integer, so I am comparing numbers to numbers

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing numbers with numbers and not numbers with strings or something like that? Try converting everything to numbers before comparing.

Comment: I am pretty sure both are numbers. LastRow is defined as an Integer.

Comment: thanks for the really quick help by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tip - use the `Val()` function on any expression to ensure that you are comparing numbers with numbers.  Val() returns 0 if the expression cannot be converted - which can also be useful sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I used the val() function and it works. Thanks for the tip!

val(Cells(LastRow, 1).Value )

Dont really understand why i Need this though